# Connect to kafka running in Azure Container Instance from outside

Tags: azure, docker, apache-kafka, azure-container-instances

I have a kafka instance running in Azure Container instance. I want to connect to it (send messages) from outside the container (from application running on external server/local computer or another container).

After searching the internet, I understand that we need to provide the external IpAddress  to kafka listener which would be listening from outside to connect.

Eg: `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafkaserver:29092,PLAINTEXT://<ip-address>:9092`

But since azure container instance gets ip address after it has spin up how can we connect in this case?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.1
      container_name: zookeeper
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 39999
      volumes:
        - ../zookeeper_data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
        - ../zookeeper_log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
      networks:
        - app_net

    #*************kafka***************
    kafkaserver:
      image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.0.1
      container_name: kafkaserver
      ports:
      # To learn about configuring Kafka for access across networks see
      # https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
        - "9092:9092"
      depends_on:
        - zookeeper
      environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafkaserver:29092,PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
        KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 49999
      volumes:
        - ../kafka_data:/var/lib/kafka/data      
      networks:
        - app_net
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an EventHubs cluster with Kafka support instead...

But if you want to run Kafka in Docker, the Confluent image would need extended with your own Dockerfile that would inject your own shell script [between these lines](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images/blob/master/kafka/include/etc/confluent/docker/run#L31-L35) which would use some shell command to fetch the external listener defined at runtime.

e.g. Create `aci-run` file with this section

```
echo "===> Configuring for ACI networking ..."
/etc/confluent/docker/aci-override

echo "===> Configuring ..."
/etc/confluent/docker/configure

echo "===> Running preflight checks ... "
/etc/confluent/docker/ensure
```

(Might need `source /etc/confluent/docker/aci-override` ... I haven't tested this)

Create a Dockerfile like so and build/push to your registry

```
ARG CONFLUENT_VERSION=7.0.1
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka:${CONFLUENT_VERSION}
COPY aci-override /etc/confluent/docker/aci-override
COPY aci-run /etc/confluent/docker/run  # override this file
```

In `aci-override`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ACI_IP=...
ACI_EXTERNAL_PORT=...
ACI_SERVICE_NAME=...

export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${ACI_IP}:${ACI_EXTERNAL_PORT}
```

You can remove `localhost` listener since you want to connect externally.

Then update the YAML to run that image.

I know Heroku, Apache Mesos, Kubernetes, etc all set some `PORT` environment variable within the container when it starts. I'm not sure what that is for ACI, but if you can `exec` into a simple running container and run `env`, you might see it.